# Accessing array element from response data using react-query

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-query

I am using react-query to make a GET request to my API in which the response is an array of objects. Each object has 1 property which is the name that I want to access. When I log the response to the console, it appears like the image listed at the bottom. Even says the prototype is an array. However, when I try to access an element of the response, it says "cannot read properties of undefined".

Here is the code which displays the data as shown in the image:

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('cat_names', () =>
        fetch('<api-link>').then(res =>
            res.json()
        )
    )
console.log(data)
```

Here is the code I used to try accessing the first element of the array.

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('cat_names', () =>
   fetch('<api-link>').then(res =>
       res.json()
   )
)
console.log(data[0])
```

I have also tried mapping data, with no luck:

```
const mapped_data = data.map(element => element.name)
console.log(mapped_data)
```

[image]

Comment: It's most likely because your data is initially undefined when the component first renders before the request comes back. If you try something like `if(data) console.log(data[0])` the error will definitely go away

Comment: Haha yep, you are correct. Thank you, sir!

Comment: You are welcome